# How to search Knowledge Articles bypassing Guest user permissions in Napili Community?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, sosl, napili

**Background:**

1. We have a public page on Napili community where guest user can type the search term into the custom search component and see the results.
2. If we use the OOB Napili search functionality, it is not showing all the articles matching the search term but only what guest user can see.
3. So we built a custom search component as mentioned in this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_search_and_profile.htm) hoping that we can bypass user permissions.

But still we are getting results based on user permissions.

Here is the complete code for the component:

**CommunityCustomSearch.cmp:**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:searchInterface" 
                access="global" 
                controller="ComunityCustomSearchApexController">

    <div class="search">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
            <form class="search-form">
                <div class="search-input-wrapper" style="display:inline-block">
                    <input  style="width:100%" 
                            aura:id="search-input" 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="My Search"/>
                </div>
                <button type="button" 
                        onclick="{!c.searchBtnHandler}">
                    <span   class=" label bBody truncate" 
                            dir="ltr">Search</span>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**CommunityCustomSearchController.js:**

```
({
    searchBtnHandler : function(component, event, helper) {

        var searchText = component.find('search-input').getElement().value;
        console.log(searchText);

        var action = component.get("c.searchArticles");
        action.setParams({  searchTerm : searchText});

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                console.log('Server call SUCCESS');
                console.log('Results returned from server ');
                console.log(response.getReturnValue().length);
                console.log(response.getReturnValue()[0].articleTitle);
            }else{
                console.log('Server call for getting Search Results failed');
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**ComunityCustomSearchApexController.cls:**

```
public without sharing class ComunityCustomSearchApexController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<SearchResultsWrapper> searchArticles(String searchTerm){

        String sosl = 'FIND \'*' + searchTerm + '*\' IN ALL FIELDs';
        sosl = sosl + ' Returning Knowledge__kav(ID, Title,UrlName ';
        sosl = sosl + ' WHERE PublishStatus = \'Online\'';
        sosl = sosl + ' AND Language = \'en_US\')  WITH SNIPPET (target_length=120)';
        Search.SearchResults searchResults = search.find(sosl);

        List<Search.SearchResult> articleList = searchResults.get('Knowledge__kav');

        List<SearchResultsWrapper> wrapperList = new List<SearchResultsWrapper>();

        for (Search.SearchResult searchResult : articleList) {
            Knowledge__kav article = (Knowledge__kav) searchResult.getSObject();
            SearchResultsWrapper obj = new SearchResultsWrapper();
            obj.articleTitle = article.Title;
            wrapperList.add(obj);
        }

        System.debug(JSON.serialize(wrapperList));
        return wrapperList;
    }

    public class SearchResultsWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public String articleTitle;
    }

}
```

**Data:**

1. I have two articles in the system.
2. One article is accessible by Guest users(`IsVisibleInPkb = TRUE`)
3. Another article is accessible only for Community users(`IsVisibleInCsp = TRUE`).

**Results:**

1. If I access this component as guest user and type the search term, I am seeing only one result in the console.
2. When I access the same component wrapped in a `aura:application` as an internal user and for the same search term, I am seeing two results in the console.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite obvious that user won't get access to Article, until unless it is published for user's channel.

For public community users, you will have to publish the second article for PKB (Public Knowledge Base) channel.

Regarding the link, you can customise the search component to control your search behaviour for other standard and custom objects, but Article sharing and permissions are designed in more controlled manner and are managed by Salesforce.

For example, you can control following operations for articles in your customised search component:

- Display only specific type of article types
- Display only 2 records out of available 5 records, based on certain conditions

However article sharing with user will be controlled by Channels and Data category access.

A possible workaround to search Articles with Guest user profile:

- Implement a custom object to store Article Title, Summary, URL and ID and keep it in sync with Knowledge Articles, even they are not published for Public Knowledge base
- Grant access to Guest user to this custom object. So even an article is not accessible, he would be able query the title
- If the user selects the article, navigate to login page or article URL

Comment: I understand that user does not have access to the article thats why I am using controller so that user permissions are ignored. You don't think so?

Comment: Just by using Without sharing controller, user will not gain access to all articles. I have updated my answer to include a bit more detail.

Comment: Is it documented that knowledge articles always respect user permissions even though it is without sharing??

Comment: You are confusing in two different things - You will be able to query the article type using Without Sharing keyword, if user doesn't have access to that type (Results into articleName__kav object), given article is published for that channel and user has access to associated data categories. But you won't be able to bypass channel and Data category sharing by any means.

Comment: Please see this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/58360/16304 I am trying to implement this functionality. If user clicks on the article thay he doesn't have access then I am planning to show login page as mentioned in this answer. Do you think the idea mentioned in this answer won't work?

Comment: That's a totally different scenario, you described in your problem statement. Again there are two part in the link you have shared: 1) Redirecting the user to proper knowledge article page, after handling the authentication. 2) Display the article. You will be able to manage 1st part without any problem, but for 2nd the user will need access to that article in Customer Community channel.

Comment: If we cannot bypass channel and data category then I am confused as what is salesforce trying to give by offering us to implement custom search component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time. I am going to try few things based on this discussion and post my results here. Thanks again!

Comment: Custom search component would also be applicable to all other objects and you can restrict them based on certain behaviour. Also read the answer again, I have included one search scenario there for articles. I will keep an eye on this thread for your progress, good luck.

Comment: Based on your answer, I did more research and found this official salesforce article (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206121&type=1) and it says this `Conversely, the article will be returned in SOSL searches performed by this user (through API or via Apex code invoked by the controller of a Visualforce page) if the article is visible to the user.` which supports your point.

Comment: For now, As a workaround(kind of hacky solution), we are making a REST call under sysadmin profile so guest user sees irrespective of his permissions and when the guest user clicks on the article which he doesn't have access we are showing login page. You can update your answer with these points so that it is useful for future readers. Thanks again!

Comment: I would like that idea of yours by wasting a license. I would recommend to implement a custom object to store Article Title, Summary and ID. Provide access to the guest user and implement search component to return this object records. If user selects any of the article, build the dynamic URL and redirect to respective page. Also mark the solution as Best Answer to help others :)

Comment: We did considered about license vs custom object. There are many features with knowledge article object like  votestat,viewstat,number of cases linked to articles, relation with topics and etc. I don't think we are wasting license because we already have integration user id in system used for other purposes. We felt custom object is extra overhead also if there are any kind of enhancements to Knowledge Articles in the future releases then we have to maintain code to keep custom object in sync.

Comment: Custom object will be only used for searching the article text and will be navigated back to Proper knowledge article page, which would internally use vote, view and associated cases. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57976/discussion-between-javanoob-and-salesforcesmarty).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to accept @Salesforcesmarty answer as it led me in the right direction but below are things I learnt and wanted to share as a separate answer.

From [Troubleshooting Article Visibility - Salesforce help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206121&type=1)

> An article will not be searchable if the user cannot open the direct
>   link to the article. If the user navigates to the direct link to the
>   article, and the article is displayed, the above conditions will be
>   met for the given article. **Conversely, the article will be returned in
>   SOSL searches performed by this user (through API or via Apex code
>   invoked by the controller of a Visualforce page) if the article is
>   visible to the user**.

I was wrong in thinking that custom search component runs in system mode we can show at least title of the Knowledge article though user does not have permission to see the actual record.

Two options:

1. Have a custom object storing the title and name of the Knowledge articles and do a search in this object when guest user types search term in custom component.
2. Once the guest user types the search term into custom component and hits the search button, on the server side, Do a REST callout to the actual method which does the SOSL under different user session Id.

We implemented option 2 because there are lot of SOQL and SOSL features that are specific to Knowledge Articles and we will lose those if we go with custom object approach. Downside of option 2 is it consumes API calls but thats ok for us as this functionality is used by very few people in production.

The ultimate goal in showing the title of Knowledge article for which guest user does not have access to is to show login screen when guest user clicks on the article link to see the actual record.